# student ranking ties score php code

Tags: php, ranking

Please help me in ranking with a formula like for example:

```
std_no    score        rank  

 1        50           1
 4        45           2
 3        45           3
 2        45           4
 5        45           5
 6        30           6
```

the above example is correct but i want this like.

```
std_no   score        rank  

 1       50            1
 4       45            3.5
 3       45            3.5
 2       45            3.5
 5       45            3.5
 6       30            6
```

how i get 3.5? formula rank. 2,3,4,5 add then divided 4 which is the quantity of same rank 45.

Comment: At least show your code

Comment: Normally the 4 students with same score should be all 2nd and not 3.5.

Comment: std_no should not be unique ? because theer is 2 std_no 1

Comment: but the formula is add the rank of all same score and divided it to quantity of same score

Comment: @binogure sorry wrong type

Comment: Your forumla is: (min rank + max rank) / 2 (for the same score)

Comment: how to get min rank and max rank php code

Comment: i use array=(50,45,45,45,45,30)

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no tag or language specified i choose perl (to convert to php: http://www.cs.wcupa.edu/~rkline/perl2php/):

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Data::Dumper;
    use Clone qw(clone);

    sub _minRank
    {
        my ($couple, $tmpInput)    = @_;
        my $minRank                = @$couple[1];

        foreach my $key (keys %{$tmpInput}) {
            my $StudentCouple = $tmpInput->{$key};

            if (@$StudentCouple[0] == @$couple[0] && @$StudentCouple[1] < $minRank) {
                $minRank = @$StudentCouple[1];
            }
        }
        return $minRank;
    }

    sub _maxRank
    {
        my ($couple, $tmpInput)    = @_;
        my $maxRank                = @$couple[1];

        foreach my $key (keys %{$tmpInput}) {
            my $StudentCouple = $tmpInput->{$key};

            if (@$StudentCouple[0] == @$couple[0] && @$StudentCouple[1] > $maxRank) {
                $maxRank = @$StudentCouple[1];
            }
        }
        return $maxRank;
    }

    sub _nbIteration
    {
        my ($couple, $tmpInput)    = @_;
        my $nbIteration            = 0;

        foreach my $key (keys %{$tmpInput}) {
            my $StudentCouple = $tmpInput->{$key};

            if (@$StudentCouple[0] == @$couple[0]) {
                $nbIteration++;
            }
        }

        return $nbIteration;
    }

    sub _computeRank
    {
        my ($couple, $tmpInput) = @_;

        my $tmpInput1   = $tmpInput;
        my $nbIteration = _nbIteration($couple, $tmpInput1);
        my $rank        = @$couple[1];

        if ($nbIteration > 1) {
            my $tmpInput2   = $tmpInput;
            my $minRank     = _minRank($couple, $tmpInput2);

            my $tmpInput3   = $tmpInput;
            my $maxRank     = _maxRank($couple, $tmpInput3);

            $rank = ($minRank + $maxRank) / 2;
        }

        return $rank;
    }

    #         Std_no => [score, rank]
    my %input = (  1 => [50, 1], 
                   4 => [45, 2], 
                   3 => [45, 3], 
                   2 => [45, 4],
                   5 => [45, 5], 
                   6 => [30, 6] );

    my %output = %{clone(\%input)};

    foreach my $key (keys %input) {
        my $StudentCouple  = $input{$key};
        my %tmpInput       = %input;
        my $outputCouple   = $output{$key};

        @$outputCouple[1] = _computeRank($StudentCouple, \%tmpInput);
    }

    print Dumper(\%output);
```

I hope its gonna help you.

Warning !! this code is not optimized !!